# Liferay Web Form recaptcha issue on SSL reverse proxied site

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, liferay-6, recaptcha, reverse-proxy

Our installation of **Liferay Tomcat 6.2 EE bundle** is behind an **Apache HTTPD** reverse proxy server with the SSL terminating at the load balancer. We do not have any **SSL** configuration on **Tomcat 7** and are not using AJP.

We ran into an issue with using the web form portlet with the **reCaptcha** on the default site using **SSL**. The **reCaptcha** image was not rendered on the web form after configuring **reCaptcha** in the Control panel and then configuring the web form to use **reCaptcha**.

**ReCaptcha** worked on another **HTTP Liferay 6.2 EE** installation and site without an issue.

There were errors in the console in Firefox and Chrome:
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=asabsds50"[Learn More]

The **reCaptcha** call seemed to be made using http not https.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Liferay needs to have the tomcat configured in the server.xml to specify redirectport to be the same as the port tomcat is listening on ex. 8080 and adding the secure flag set to true. Restart Tomcat and test.

Apache reverse proxy in our case points to this port. This configuration worked. Now reCaptcha renders and the web forms submits successfully.

```
<Connector port="listeningport" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" secure="true"
               redirectPort="listeningport" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

The old server.xml config was

```
<Connector port="listeningport" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Hope this helps